# CNN Transfer Learning Takes Too Much Time

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I'm trying to train my model with transfer learning with Vgg16 via Google Colab(using GPU) but it takes too time and validation and test accuracy is low.
Additional informations; Train data is 16057 , test data is 4000, validation data is 2000 with different sized rgb images. Classes facial mood expressions (Happy,Sad,Energetic,Neutral) .Any suggestion ??

```
#source root directory and distination root directory
train_src = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Affectnet/train_class/"
val_src = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Affectnet/val_class/"
test_src="/content/drive/MyDrive/Affectnet/test_classs/"
train_datagen = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255, 
      rotation_range=40, 
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest'
      )
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_src,
        target_size=(224,224),
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=True
        )
validation_datagen = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255
        )

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_src,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        )
conv_base = tensorflow.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
                  )

for layer in conv_base.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
# An empyty model is created.
model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()

# VGG16 is added as convolutional layer.
model.add(conv_base)

# Layers are converted from matrices to a vector.
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten())

# Our neural layer is added.
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      epochs=50,
      steps_per_epoch=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=5)
```

[Training Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3RDB.png)

EDIT= I set the workers = 8 and model started training faster but i took .69 test accuracy after 30 epoch . Any Suggestion ?

Comment: How much is *too* much? Do you have reasons to believe that it *should* be shorter, or you just don't like it that it takes that long?

Comment: Just one epoch took 2353 secs , do you think it is normal?

Comment: Issue most likely related to "ImageDataGenerator", try using workers=8 in your fit_generator.

Comment: thanks a lot ! it worked @ahmethamzaemra

Answer (score 1):

Issue most likely related to "ImageDataGenerator", try using workers=8 in your fit_generator.